# changed /etc permission in oneiric (ubuntu11.10) by using "sudo chmod 665 /etc" cant use sudo now

Tags: permissions, sudo

I screwed up big time. I changed the permission of `/etc` in ubuntu 11.10 by using following command

```
sudo chmod 665 /etc
```

now when ever i try to use sudo it gives the following error:

```
sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated because i am new to Ubuntu. I have already tried using `su` but it doesnt even login as root and even i give it the right password it always say `Authentication Failure`. I don't want to login as root coz its risky and even a newbie in Linux like me is not stupid enough to have such control. I just want to use my `sudo` again. I have tried to go into recovery mode as well but I can't get in to recovery mode.

Answer (score 7):

[Boot the recovery console option](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).
Select remount read-write
Select root shell

```
cd /
chmod 755 etc <--to get it back to default  
sync
init 6
```

Comment: i dont know how to boot the recovery console option....i am really sorry but could you give me some hints on how to do it...i.e. boot the recovery console option?

Comment: You got the arguments the wrong way around there. `chmod 755 /etc`

Comment: thanx for the help......my problem is fixed.....happy coding

Comment: I think that should be `/etc`?

Comment: @Tim Changed directory to / first.  Don't like absolute urls.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice. Any reason why?

Comment: [Habit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502254/is-the-command-sudo-rm-desktop-filename-safe/502260#502260)

Comment: LIFE SAVER. ty :D

Answer (score 3):

You can generally fix this sort of problem without booting into recovery mode, without using a live CD, and without rebooting at all. An Ubuntu system with a GUI (as opposed to an Ubuntu Server system with no GUI installed) has two mechanisms for running commands as root. One is [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html). The other is [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html). You can use [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html), the command-line frontend to PolicyKit, to fix the permissions:

```
pkexec chmod 755 /etc
```

If all you did to create the problem was to run `sudo chmod 665 /etc`, then that completely fixes the problem and you don't need to try to repair any permissions *inside* `/etc`. (Nothing inside `/etc` is changed with a `chmod` command on `/etc` that doesn't use the `-R` flag.)

Comment: +1 for pkexec: surely the most easy and quick way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the the ubuntu live cd, open up the terminal and enter

1. `sudo su -`
2. `mount /dev/sda5 (or whichever is the root partition of your Ubuntu installation) /mnt`
3. `chroot /mnt`
4. `chmod 755 /etc`
5. `exit`

This should make things as they were.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`. Try to do this in rescue mode or pass `init=/bin/bash` to boot command line. Ask if you need more info.

Comment: well to be honest i dont know how to go in rescue mode.....i know this is a stupid question but please tell me how to go in rescue mode.....boot menu shows 2 options only 
Windows7
ubuntu

Comment: Try liveCD. Anyway, to run sudo you need to `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

your boot-manager-OS-List looks like the windows-bootmanager, not the ubuntu-grub-bootmanager, which would give you the option to get into recovery mode.

i don't actually know if the system installs grub anywhere anyway, but when you select ubuntu try holding shift to get into the grub-menu (if existent).

Another way would be to edit the boot.ini-file on your windows-partition. There should be an entry for ubuntu. Try appending an 1 to this line and boot into ubuntu. The 1 ends you up in single-user-mode - a command line with root-access to your system.

But the easiest way is a life-CD for sure!!!