# How to reset default permissions for /etc?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, etc

By mistake I have made permission changes for `/etc`. Now it's giving me the following error message:

```
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied  
I have no name!@chandan-Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart  
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied  
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting  
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115358/changed-etc-permission-in-oneiric-ubuntu11-10-by-using-sudo-chmod-665-etc?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

What I would do :

```
$ sudo su
chown -R root:root /etc
find /etc -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find /etc -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/* /etc/rc.local /etc/network/* /etc/cron.*/*
chmod 400 /etc/ssh/ssh*key
```

Maybe it's not sufficient, but without any backup, that's a good start.

Comment: Solved for me! Thks.

Answer (score 6):

As a next step after sputnik recommendation, you could  do this:
On a fresh install  of a ubuntu server with the same version as your broken one,  run this:

```
find /etc -type f -executable | awk '{printf("chmod a+x %s\n",$0);}' > setexec.sh
```

Then import the script setexec.sh (using wget or ftp)  and execute it on the broken server.
on ubuntu 13.04 this step restored most of the functionalities.

Comment: here is a list from my desktop: http://askubuntu.com/questions/508359/restore-default-system-file-folder-permessions/508366#508366

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I used a variant of it to copy all permissions, not just the execute bit: `find /etc/ -exec stat -c "chmod %a %n" '{}' \; > setperms.sh`