# Wrong Permission to /etc folder

Tags: sudo, etc, su

I given wrong permission to the /etc folder wrongly

```
chmod -R 777 /etc
```

While i want to login as root it gives me error and gives the following output.

How can i give the correct permission and fix this ?

```
system13@motpl:~$ sudo su
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
system13@motpl:~$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
system13@motpl:~$
```

Comment: `/etc` is only writeable by root as default. Did you `chmod` initially as root? Can you just revert?

Comment: I gave full permission (777) to /etc folder as a root. Now i can't login as a root as said in the question.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand the problem now.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115358/changed-etc-permission-in-oneiric-ubuntu11-10-by-using-sudo-chmod-665-etc

Comment: @Sparhawk indeed, the answer applies.

Comment: Actually, hopefully it's clear, but use the answers for the `/etc` directory instead of just `/etc/sudoers`. Also, @SulthanAllaudeen, for future reference, `sudo chmod` is preferred, but if you really want to log in as root, use `sudo -i`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes thanks you. And then i fixed the error and its working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem was fixed :**

I typed `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`

And then the permission was changed and then i gave the default permission /etc as  `chmod 744 /etc`