# Revert system fie premissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, etc

I have mistakely changed the permission of the entire `etc` directory to  `777`.

Now I'm getting frequent errors like  ... is world writable!

Is there a way to revert back to the default permission?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the exact command you typed? Please edit it into your question (check your history in bash if unsure).

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466145/wrong-permission-to-etc-folder and http://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440

Comment: couldn't find the exact history (am using ohmyzsh shell). I did sth like ```chmod 777 -R /etc```

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: That's what backups are for. ;)