# Why I can not remove neither folder nor its content?

Tags: rm

Here is the folder and its content.I don't understand why I cannot remove these files and this folder.
`ls -ltr` results in:

```
total 16672704
-rwxrwxrwx 0 17064381527 Eyl  2 18:10 101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99_merged.bam
-rwxrwxrwx 0 8395632 Eyl  2 18:10 101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99_merged.bam.bai
-rwxrwxrwx 0 4503304 Eyl  2 19:52 101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99.g.vcf.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 0 49778 Eyl  2 19:54 output.txt
```

sudo rm -rf * results in:

```
rm: cannot remove '101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99.g.vcf.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99_merged.bam': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '101737-31-HO-EO_L03_99_merged.bam.bai': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'output.txt': No such file or directory
```

Using `sudo rm -rf merged_bam_bai` to delete the whole folder doesn't help either.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Have you tried when `merged_bam_bai` isn't your working directory?

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon Yes I did. It says rm: cannot remove 'merged_bam_bai/': Directory not empty

Comment: Nope using sudo  doesn't help. @TBr

Comment: Try deleting each file independently first and empty the directory.

Comment: @TBr These files are created by using GATK bioinformatics tools. And this is the first time this has happened. And yeah I used these tools with nohup as gnks user.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your terminal.  Copy-paste and use code fences for formatting. Put three back ticks on the line before and three back ticks on the line after code blocks. Thanks

Comment: @TBr Trying to delete each file independently doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you used this tool with this VM before?  And yes definitely remove those pics per Nmath

Comment: @TBr Yes this is not the first time. I run this process to get such files many many times.

Comment: I wonder if this might be related to one file being about a hundred times the total size of all the files?

Comment: What is the filesystem that this is on?

Comment: That `ls -l` output is strange. After the permissions field (`-rwxrwxrwx`), there is a number of 0 links to the file (there should be at least 1), and there are no owner/group fields. Is this directory maybe some network share? If yes, it may be mounted read-only, that's why you can't delete.

Comment: Somehow problem has been solved. I am not sure but maybe some process was still running in the background and when it stopped files got removed. I don't know about the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use `sudo rm` to remove them, but read this first: [Is the command `sudo rm /Desktop/filename` safe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502254/is-the-command-sudo-rm-desktop-filename-safe)   To be safe run an `ls` command first to be sure you capture ONLY the files you intend to delete, then replace the `ls` with `sudo rm`